# mpi gather collect data

Tags: mpi, collect

I convinced that `MPI_Gather` collects data from all processes including root process itself.

How to make `MPI_Gather` to collect data from all process NOT including root process itself?
Or is there any alternative function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duplicate the functionality of `MPI_Gather` using `MPI_Gatherv` but specify `0` as the chunk size for the root rank instead. Something like this:

```c
int rank, size, disp = 0;
int *cnts, *displs;

MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

cnts = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
displs = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
for (rank = 0; rank < size; rank++)
{
    cnts[i] = (rank != root) ? count : 0;
    displs[i] = disp;
    disp += cnts[i];
}

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

MPI_Gatherv(data, cnts[rank], data_type,
            bigdata, cnts, displs, data_type,
            root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

free(displs); free(cnts);
```

Note that `MPI_Gatherv` could be significantly slower than `MPI_Gather` because the MPI implementation would be most likely unable to optimise the communication path and would fall back to some dumb linear implementation of the gather operation. So it might make sense to still use `MPI_Gather` and to provide some dummy data in the root process.

You could also supply `MPI_IN_PLACE` as the value of the root process send buffer and it would not send data to itself, but then again you would have to reserve place for the root data in the receive buffer (the in-place operation expects that the root would place its data directly in the correct position inside the receive buffer):

```
if (rank != root)
    MPI_Gather(data, count, data_type,
               NULL, count, data_type, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
else
    MPI_Gather(MPI_IN_PLACE, count, data_type,
               big_data, count, data_type, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```